# Unable to use "graphics.h" header file in 12.04

Tags: graphics, c

I am new to Ubuntu and I need to write some graphics programs in C which uses the header file `graphics.h` , but I am not being able to run any of my code without that header file, which is not present in any package by default. I can't understand what to do to fix this problem.

I tried a lot of things suggested by some sites like [this](http://www.rajivnair.in/2007/07/graphicsh-in-gnulinux.html) but to no avail. There were errors in the process.

I need to finish my project. Please help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

graphics.h header file is not included in any package in ubuntu because it is NOT a part of the [Standard C library](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/index.html&ei=GO8wUfXzPO-aiAeRr4DIBw&usg=AFQjCNFvKOFWEYOMhnP94B4SmAQ4xZdRSw&sig2=7y6xuEBc0sU8l1U4oSF15w&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk)

you can make use of the non-standard [ncurses](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAD&url=http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/&ei=SO8wUaSPL-STiQea8oCwAw&usg=AFQjCNFGkqiGw6xBQLnY-JKx7BjK7ydmkw&sig2=fNd62bs4MF-Pz3LVXdYyiw) library if you want to make use of the graphics function.

Hope that helps